# When pasting, how can I ignore hidden columns in the destination range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two worksheets `s1` and `s2`.

Data on `s1` looks like:

```
+---+-----------+--------+------+
|   |     A     |   B    |  C   |
+---+-----------+--------+------+
| 1 | scarecrow | tinman | lion |
+---+-----------+--------+------+
```

On `s2`, column B is hidden, like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   | A | C | D |
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
```

When I try to copy `'s1'!A1:C1` to `'s2'!A1:D1`, I get this:

```
+---+-----------+------+---+
|   |     A     |  C   | D |
+---+-----------+------+---+
| 1 | scarecrow | lion |   |
+---+-----------+------+---+
```

But I want the paste to ignore the hidden column B and give me this:

```
+---+-----------+--------+------+
|   |     A     |   C    |  D   |
+---+-----------+--------+------+
| 1 | scarecrow | tinman | lion |
+---+-----------+--------+------+
```

How can I make the paste only apply to visible cells?

Comment: No, there isn't an easy way to do this without VBA

Comment: This would seem like a common enough operation, once you start making use of hidden columns and rows.

Comment: You inspired me to write an AutoHotKey script to handle this situation. Are you interested in an AutoHotKey solution? Or is that too far out of the scope of this question?

Comment: @Dane, if you translate it to VBA, I'm interested.  In this case I don't want a solution that relies on a 3rd party scripting language.

Comment: Can I ask why you want this? Some times, its good to explain the situation so we can think of potential alternatives. As per Raystafarian's comments, as it currently stands you need to do this with VBa

Comment: @DaveRook, the reason why is that there are several columns with formulas that have been added to `s2` in between the same columns that are in `s1`.  Other than these columns, the structure of the two sheets is the same.  If I just paste the data as-is, it overwrites the formula columns and doesn't get entered into the correct columns.

Comment: I've run into this scenario before as well. In my case, I was pulling data from a source, and running equations on columns I had inserted. I want to be able to paste updated data into the appropriate columns by hiding the equation columns.

Comment: In case somebody wants the AHK solution: https://gist.github.com/Fluffums/10162893#file-ahk-literaltabpaste-ahk

Answer (score 1):

*To  Paste data and skip hidden rows at 
 destination do the followings:*

1. Select the **Destination Range**.
2. Press `F5` then select `Special` then 
   `Visible Cells Only`.
3. Press `=` and click on the first cell 
   at your **Source Range**.
4. Press **Ctrl + Enter**.

**Note,** this should bring in data from the visible rows provided their position is identical to the destination range.

Comment: this is not working for me on excel 2013,  its the "press ="  part that is throwing me off (it just inserts the = sign into all of the selected row,  and after that im not allowed to paste).

Comment: @JamesGaul,, nice to hear from U, I've tested in 2013 and in 2016 also, and it's working,, do it like this ,,, Copy then select destination (including hidden cells/rows) press `F5` select `Visible cells only`,, then enter `=` sign then hit Source data,,, and press `Ctrl+Enter`,, you get it done !!

Answer (score 0):

You can select "visible only" and then paste.

1. Select range of cells.
2. Find & select dialog -> Go to special
3. Select "visible only" - now you selected only visible cells.
4. All you have to do now is copy & paste.

More details here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/copy-visible-cells-only-HA010244897.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear about what I want.  There are no hidden cells in the "from" range, only the "to" range.  I want to select all cells in the "from" range, and then paste them so their values get set in the visible cells in the "to" range.